# Google Cloud CSGO server can't connect

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have set up a CSGO server on Google Cloud. However, I am unable to connect - it just keeps retrying. After some research it seems like it's a firewall issue, but setting the rules to allow UDP and TCP ingress for pretty much all the ports still doesn't work. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Which ports need to be open? How did you set up the Cloud firewall and the host firewall?

Comment: I did some searching online and supposedly the ports that need to be opened are `TCP: 27015-27030,27036-27037` and `UDP: 4380,27000-27031,27036`. I just created a firewall rule on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid. I changed the firewall priority because I thought higher meant more priority. I fixed it by lowering the priority value so that it was higher priority.